# InAppBrowser Cordova IOS Deprecation Warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, inappbrowser

These warnings occur in XCode when I choose a build target greater than 6.0 when using inappbrowser in cordova. I have tried setting the build target to 7.0 and 7.1 because I found that to be a solution when searching for an answer. This does not occur if I choose a build target under 6.0. Anyone know why this is occurring?

I am using: 

XCode 5.1

Cordova 3.4.1

InAppBrowser 0.3.3

Here are the warnings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser to version 0.4.0 resolved the issue.